# Resistance of circle of wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-resistance

Today I was wondering about this situation. Let's imagine I have a circle of wire with a homogeneous section. I connect the wire with 2 terminals from ohmmeter. What minimum and maximum resistance can be measured? What resistance should I measure when terminals enclose an angle α with the center circle?

Comment: Consider whether asking for help in a running competitions Czech FYKOS(http://fykos.org/problems) and Slovak FKS (http://fks.sk) is fair or not to others. You'll learn nothing about solving physics problems, since you don't seem to be motivated to solve them. If you cannot solve them, read the solutions which will be publicly available after deadline.

Comment: Related Meta question: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4940/2451